# Eliminate inner parenthesis runs into empty list and doesn't eliminate using cons

Tags: scheme, racket, flatten

The goal is to eliminate all inner parenthesis.

> (flatten '(a (b c) d))  becomes  '(a b c d)

This is my code in Racket

```
; if slist is null, return empty
; otherwise, if it is a pair, recursively solve car and cdr and concat them
; if it is a symbol, return the symbol

(define flatten
  (lambda (slist)
    (cond
      [ (null? slist) '()]
      [ (pair? slist)  
        (cons ((flatten (car slist)) (flatten (cdr slist))))]
      [ (symbol? slist) slist])))
```

It's complaining

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: c; arguments were: ()
```

which means I am trying to access `car` and `cdr` of an empty list.

```
I did the trace:
> (flatten '(a (b c) d))
pair?-car-cdr
a
((b c) d)
symbol?
a
pair?-car-cdr
(b c)
(d)
pair?-car-cdr
b
(c)
symbol?
b
pair?-car-cdr
c
()
symbol?
c
(stops here)
```

The trace code is simple - a bunch of displays.

```
(define flatten
  (lambda (slist)
    (cond
      [ (null? slist) '()]
      [ (pair? slist) 
        (display 'pair?-car-cdr)
        (newline)
        (display (car slist))
        (newline)
        (display (cdr slist))
        (newline)
        (cons ((flatten (car slist)) (flatten (cdr slist))))]
      [ (symbol? slist) 
         (display 'symbol?)
         (newline)
         (display slist)
         (newline)
        slist])))
```

What I don't understand is how come the first condition `(null? slist)` didn't catch the empty list? I have two recursive calls. If it did catch the empty list, it would go to the next recursion which is the list `{d}`.

What is the problem with my recursion logic?

---

Update version

```
(define flatten
  (lambda (slist)
    (cond
      [ (null? slist) '()]
      [ (pair? slist)  
        (cons (flatten (car slist)) (flatten (cdr slist)))]
      [ (symbol? slist) slist])))

(display (equal? (flatten '(a (b a) b a c (a b) c (e f (b a)))) '(a b a b a c a b c e f b a)))
(newline)
(display (equal? (flatten '(a b c)) '(a b c)))
(newline)
(display (equal? (flatten '(a (b c))) '(a b c)))
(newline)
(display (equal? (flatten '((a)(b)(c) d)) '(a b c d)))
(newline)
(display (equal? (flatten '(a (b) ((c)) (((d))) ((((e (f g))))))) '(a b c d e f g )))
(newline)
(display (equal? (flatten '()) '()))
(newline)
(display (equal? (flatten '(a b () ())) '(a b)))
(newline)
```

As Ross Larson suggested, append will make the program works. But for the sake of learning, if any one have the time to spare, the result of my tests show only the base cases passed (2nd and the empty list)

I thought about writing a wrapper function which calls `(cons (flatten slist) empty)`

Comment: Just double checking: did DrRacket properly highlight the region of code `((flatten (car slist)) (flatten (cdr slist)))` which raised the error?  It should be doing so, and I want to confirm the GUI is doing the right thing.

Comment: @dyoo yes it's doing the right thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this expression:

> ((flatten (car slist)) ...)

This means, apply whatever (flatten ...) returns. But since this
returns a list, the application fails.

Change it to

> (flatten (car slist))

Comment: Yes it is doing fine with the fix, by replacing the original line into `(cons (flatten (car slist)) (flatten (cdr slist)))`  But my logic is totally wrong? Because the return is the an unmodified list. Should I open a new question?

Comment: Do you have any test cases? Which test cases work, and which does not?

Comment: Right. I did. Only bases cases will pass with `cons`. I mean Ross Larson solved the other issue by suggesting using `append`. It seems like I must have a wrapper function that calls `flatten`.

Answer (score 1):

cons is going to recreate the structure (As you have observed). Take a look into append instead.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html

(I don't address the other issues as it seems the other answers have fixed the application of the recursion value)

Comment: Yes. The append works. But if I ever use cons, is that feasiable? I thought about creating a wrapper function that calls on `flatten`.

Comment: Cons is not going to strip parens off. So if you have '((1 2) 3) you would have (cons (flatten `(1 2)) (flatten '(3))) both of those are flat lists, so cons is just going to have (cons '(1 2) '(3)) and the '(1 2) will be put in car position of the list '(3). (append will take out each element in a list and add them to the second list individually.