# One liner using j to make nested lists into one list

Tags: python, list, nested

```
j= lambda l:reduce(lambda a,b:a+b,l)
k= lambda l:map(lambda z:j(z),map(lambda x:k(x) if type(x)==list else [x],l))
```

Type Error: it prints [1, 14] for print k([1,[2,[3,4],5]])

Comment: Sometimes, one liners are a pain to the eyes

Comment: So I am just curious on your approach to this, did you try to write this out as a mulit line function before converting to a one liner?

That way you can verify your code was working before optimizing it into a one liner

Comment: Maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) you can find something

Comment: yes with a multi line function it's much easier

Comment: @Novak the solution is only for 2 in depth, i need it to be for infinite depth

Comment: Can you possibly add the mulit line function to the post so I can see what you are converting from?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution proposed in:

> [Flattening a list recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472338/flattening-a-list-recursively)

```
flatten=lambda l: sum(map(flatten,l),[]) if isinstance(l,list) else [l]
```