# How to check what data types are in a list, no matter how deep the the list is

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list I would like to check what data types are in it, no matter how many levels deep the list goes.
I first thought to do this:

```py
all([isinstance(x, (int, float, str, bytes, list, tuple, set, dict)) for x in l])
```

But it doesn't seem to work:

```py
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, [bytearray(b'1234')]]
>>> all([isinstance(x, (int, float, str, bytes, list, tuple, set, dict)) for x in l])
True
```

Is there another method to do this? One that works?

Comment: Flatten the list, then check every element of that. See [Flattening a list recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472338/flattening-a-list-recursively)

Comment: What type does you want to check?

Comment: `(int, float, str, bytes, list, tuple, set, dict, bytearray)` I would like to check that **only** these data types are in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following `flatten` function:

```
def flatten(s):
    for e in s:
        if isinstance(e, (tuple, list)):
            yield from flatten(e)
        else:
            yield e

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, [bytearray(b'1234')]]

result = all(isinstance(x, (int, float, str, bytes, list, tuple, set, dict)) for x in flatten(l))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
False
```

The advantage of this approach is that you wont have to check the entire list, [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) will short-circuit if it finds a `False`.

Comment: Will this work even in the unlikely event that the list is say 900 levels deep?

Comment: It is a recursive function, so I guess you have to change the number of calls that can be made.

Comment: So it's only limited by until a `RecursionError` is called?

Comment: @LittleBlueDragon yes, see here how to increase the limit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it