# How to show all tables in all databases in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

The following can be used to show table in the current schema or a specified schema respectively:

```
show tables;

show tables in my_schema;
```

This documented here:
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/show-tables.html

Is there a way to show all tables in all databases?

Are there metadata tables in Databricks/Spark (similar to the all_ or dba_ tables in Oracle or the information_schema in MySql)?  Is there a way to do more specific queries about database objects in Databricks?  Something like this:

```
select * from i_dont_know_what where lower(table_name) like '%gold%' and schema = 'myschema';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see all the databases and Tables in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013666/how-to-see-all-the-databases-and-tables-in-databricks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you use spark catalog apis on databricks? please try this-

```scala
val tuples: Map[String, String] = spark.catalog.listDatabases().collect().flatMap(db =>
      spark.catalog.listTables(db.name).collect().map(x => (db.name, x.name))
    ).toMap
```

Comment: This looks like its pulling all of the data and then filtering.  I'm currently doing something in Java.  I was hoping there is a way to do this in sql.

Comment: Here there is no expression to pull the data from the db. we are just pulling the metadata

Comment: @Som Could you please give the same code in Python?

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi I have provided code in Python in a separate answer if you still need it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73131488/6201129

Answer (score 9):

I tried different ways of obtaining all tables in all schemas but the following is the fastest and most efficient way in Python

```py
databases = [
    db.databaseName 
    for db in spark.sql('show databases').collect()
]
tables = [
    f"{row['database']}.{row['tableName']}" #<schema>.<table> format
    for db_rows in [
        spark.sql(f'show tables in {db}').collect() for db in databases
    ] 
    for row in db_rows
]
print(tables)
```

Tested it with around 160 schemas that have total of around 3300 tables and it took around 7 seconds on **r5n.xlarge** cluster.

Comment: Awesome! Runs like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. I wrote a short article about it as well: https://medium.com/helmes-people/how-to-view-all-databases-tables-and-columns-in-databricks-9683b12fee10

The output is a Spark SQL view which holds **database name**, **table name**, and **column name**. This is for all databases, all tables and all columns.
You could extend it to have more information. Good part about it, which I needed, was that it lists also the nested columns (StructType).

---

*Edit 2022-02-21: added columns for column **dataType** and **nullable** values.*

---

Pyspark code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

# get field name from schema (recursive for getting nested values)
def get_schema_field_name(field, parent=None):
  if type(field.dataType) == StructType:
    if parent == None:
      prt = field.name
    else:
      prt = parent+"."+field.name # using dot notation
    res = []
    for i in field.dataType.fields:
      res.append(get_schema_field_name(i, prt))
    return res
  else:
    if parent==None:
      res = {"name": field.name, "dataType": str(field.dataType), "nullable": field.nullable}
    else:
      res = {"name": parent+"."+field.name, "dataType": str(field.dataType), "nullable": field.nullable}
    return res
  
# flatten list, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472564/4920394
def flatten(S):
  if S == []:
    return S
  if isinstance(S[0], list):
    return flatten(S[0]) + flatten(S[1:])
  return S[:1] + flatten(S[1:])

# list of databases
db_list = [x[0] for x in spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").rdd.collect()]

for i in db_list:
  spark.sql("SHOW TABLES IN {}".format(i)).createOrReplaceTempView(str(i)+"TablesList")

# create a query for fetching all tables from all databases
union_string = "SELECT database, tableName FROM "
for idx, item in enumerate(db_list):
  if idx == 0:
    union_string += str(item)+"TablesList WHERE isTemporary = 'false'"
  else:
    union_string += " UNION ALL SELECT database, tableName FROM {}".format(str(item)+"TablesList WHERE isTemporary = 'false'")
spark.sql(union_string).createOrReplaceTempView("allTables")

# full list = schema, table, column
full_list = []
for i in spark.sql("SELECT * FROM allTables").collect():
  table_name = i[0]+"."+i[1]
  table_schema = spark.table(table_name)
  column_list = []
  for j in table_schema.schema:
    column_list.append(get_schema_field_name(j))
  column_list = flatten(column_list)
  for k in column_list:
    full_list.append([i[0],i[1],k["name"], k["dataType"], k["nullable"]])
spark.createDataFrame(full_list, schema = ['database', 'tableName', 'columnName', "dataType", "nullable"]).createOrReplaceTempView("allColumns")
```

Comment: thanks for sharing.. can you enhance this code to also include datatype in output?

Comment: @Learn2Code sure! Have a look, I updated the code. It now includes dataType and nullable fields. Based on a quick test it looks a bit clumsy for ArrayType, but otherwise seems OK.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code to list all table name in on Database

```
df = spark.sql("show tables in {}".format("<Your Database Name>"))
display(df)
```

Comment: This works to show all of the tables but I would also like to be able to query in manner similar to Oracle or MySql (e.g. select * from all_tables where table_name like 'foo%').

Answer (score 3):

This code will create an information_schema for you in hive_metastore-

```
cls = []
spark.sql("Drop view if exists allColumns")

for db in spark.sql("show databases").collect():
    for table in spark.catalog.listTables(f"{db.databaseName}"):
        for column in spark.catalog.listColumns(table.name, table.database):
            cls.append([table.database,table.name, column.name, column.dataType])
            
spark.createDataFrame(cls, schema = ['databaseName','tableName','columnName', 
'columnDataType']).createOrReplaceTempView("allColumns")

spark.sql("""create or replace table default.information_schema as select * from allColumns""")
```

Answer (score 3):

The below code gives an extended information about a table such as *location, createdtime, sizeinBytes* etc for ***Databricks*** tables.

```
tbl_details = []
# DB Names
databases = [
    db.databaseName 
    for db in spark.sql('show databases').collect()
]
# Table Names
tables = [
    f"{row['database']}.{row['tableName']}"
    for db_rows in [
        spark.sql(f'show tables in {db}').collect() for db in databases
    ] 
    for row in db_rows
]
# Table details
table_details = [{
'id':row['id'],
'name':row['name'],
'description':row['description'],
'location':row['location'],
'createdAt':row['createdAt'],
'lastModified':row['lastModified'],
'partitionColumns':row['partitionColumns'],
'numFiles':row['numFiles'],
'sizeInBytes':row['sizeInBytes'],
'minReaderVersion':row['minReaderVersion'],
'minWriterVersion':row['minWriterVersion']
}
for tbl_rows in [
  spark.sql(f'describe detail {tbl}').collect() for tbl in tables
]
for row in tbl_rows
]
#Print extended table details
print(table_details)

#A Spark DF containing table details
df_all_tbl_details = spark.createDataFrame(table_details)
df_all_tbl_details.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm updating the answer for 2024 with Unity Catalog and system tables:

```
SELECT * FROM `system`.information_schema.tables
AND table_owner != 'System user'
```

You can of course remove the filter on 'System user' if you want really all tables even system ones.