# How to see all the databases and Tables in Databricks

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

i want to list all the tables in every database in Azure Databricks.

so i want the output to look somewhat like this:

```
Database | Table_name
Database1 | Table_1
Database1 | Table_2
Database1 | Table_3
Database2 | Table_1
etc..
```

This is what i have at the moment:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

DatabaseDF = spark.sql(f"show databases")
df = spark.sql(f"show Tables FROM {DatabaseDF}")
#df = df.select("databaseName")
#list = [x["databaseName"] for x in df.collect()]

print(DatabaseDF)
display(DatabaseDF)

df = spark.sql(f"show Tables FROM {schemaName}")
df = df.select("TableName")
list = [x["TableName"] for x in df.collect()]

## Iterate through list of schema
for x in list:
###  INPUT Required: Change for target table
    tempTable = x
    df2 = spark.sql(f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {schemaName}.{tempTable}").collect()
    for x in df2:
      rowCount = x[0]
      
    if rowCount == 0:
      print(schemaName + "." + tempTable + " has 0 rows")
```

but i'm not quite getting the results.

Comment: Please provide what output you get now

Answer (score 5):

There is a `catalog` property to spark session, probably what you are looking for :

```py
spark.catalog.listDatabases()
spark.catalog.listTables("database_name")
```

`listDatabases` returns the list of database you have.
`listTables` returns for a certain database name, the list of tables.

You can do something like this for example :

```py
[
    (table.database, table.name)
    for database in spark.catalog.listDatabases()
    for table in spark.catalog.listTables(database.name)
]
```

to get the list of database and tables.

---

EDIT: (thx [@Alex Ott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18627/alex-ott)) even if this solution works fine, it is quite slow.
Using directly some sql commands like `show databases` or `show tables in ...` should do the work faster.

Comment: catalog API surprisingly slow compared to the `show databases`, `show tables in ...`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ShowTablesInfo").getOrCreate()

# set the database
spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("default")

# get all tables
tables = spark.catalog.listTables()

# loop through tables and display database, table, and location
for table in tables:
    database = table.database
    name = table.name
    location = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE EXTENDED {name}").filter("Location").select("data_type").collect()[0][0]
    print(f"Database: {database}, Table: {name}, Location: {location}")

# stop the SparkSession
spark.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want managed tables

I also added try: exception section to avoid errors when location is not found

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ShowTablesInfo").getOrCreate()

# set the database
#spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("default")

# get all tables
tables = spark.catalog.listTables()

# loop through tables and display database, table, and location
for table in tables:
    database = table.database
    name = table.name
    if (table.tableType == "MANAGED"):
        try:
            location = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE EXTENDED {name}").filter("col_name = 'Location'").select("data_type").collect()[0][0]
            print(f"Database: {database}, Table: {name}, Location: {location}")
        except Exception as err:
            continue
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).