# Flattening a list of strings- have a solution but don't know why it works

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found a solution for my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372463/extracting-strings-from-nested-lists-in-python).
The thing is, my answer was exactly the same, except for `(checkio(x))`, I had just `(x)`.

So instead of this (working solution):

```
def checkio(data):

    new_list = []
    for x in data:
        if type(x) == list:
            new_list.extend(checkio(x))
        else:
            new_list.append(x)
    return new_list
```

I had:

```
def checkio(data):

new_list = []
for x in data:
    if type(x) == list:
        new_list.extend(x)
    else:
        new_list.append(x)
return new_list
```

Why doesn't that work?
Why do I need to reference the function itself?
What is `checkio(x)` exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recursively call the `checkio` function in case you have a nested list that is passed in `data`, so that the nested list gets flattened too.

For example:

```
data = ["a", "b", ["c", "d"], [["e", "f"], "g"]]
```

Comment: Ah ok! I think I get it. It uses the function again (in a different instance?) to go through x (if it's a list) and if it hits another list it goes through the function again?

Comment: Just to add why this confused me. It didn't occur to me that I could use the function within the function to loop over nested items if the function would find them. It felt like inception for a second.

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock Well, it's almost inception, it's called *recursion* ;)